# What exactly are limits used for in real life applications?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am currently taking a Survey of Calculus course and recently we started learning about these things called limits.  I know that they basically tell you what the "y" value of a function will be/be near, as "x" approaches a certain point, but I don't know what use this would be outside of finding "y" at certain points on a graph and derivatives of tangent lines (which becomes useless once you learn the "power rule.")

What exactly are limits, and what are some real life applications?  Are limits what Isaac Newton created to figure out where planets would be at certain points?

Comment: This is a slightly more general version of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365770/what-is-a-simple-example-of-a-limit-in-the-real-world

Comment: the limit as $t$ goes to infinity = long-term trend/equilibrium of a quantity

Comment: Compound interest (continous compounding)

Comment: The power rule won't get you very far in physics, electrical engineering, or mathematical finance. How does it help you differentiate $\sin x$ or $e^x$? But Newton and Leibniz actually did these things without limits, using tools that weren't so reliable in less wise hands. On the other hand, there are a lot of calculus theorems that work only for continuous functions, and the standard way to know that a function is continuous involves limits.